# Does homogeneity of spacetime and isotropy of space imply the absence of a gravitational field?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

Electromagnetic fields, masses, etc are absent. I can see that the converse of this statement is true (the frame becomes Galileian). The proof becomes trivial if gravitational field can be treated as a $3D$ vector i.e $g(x,y,z,t)=g_x i +g_yj+g_zk$, but I remember reading another PSE answer that says this is not always the case. I'm not familiar with the math of GR or anything, but I can understand vector calculus.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does homogeneity of spacetime and isotropy of space imply the absence of a gravitational field?

No. For example, [Friedmann spacetimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) are homogeneous and isotropic but have a gravitational field. Such a spacetime with zero spatial curvature (but nonzero spacetime curvature) is the current standard cosmological model for our universe and its gravitational dynamics on the largest scales.